# Need help setting up an HP Procurve 2650 switch via serial using Linux.

Tags: linux, switch, hp, hp-procurve, serial

I recently bought an HP Procurve 2650 (J4899A) off ebay and it came out without a serial cable. So I also purchased a null modem serial cable (rs232) to connect to it (Assuming this is the right one). I have plugged it into a box running debian and have been struggling to connect to it. I have tried to connect to it with Minicom and Putty with no luck.

The switch itself starts up no problem, I just seem to be having the issue with connecting to it. In putty I have set all the serial settings correctly with reference to the switches manual (ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/j489990001.pdf) but I seem to have hit a brick wall. Even though there is no option to set putty's terminal elimination to VT100 I assume it sets/detects it automatically.

Just to note I can not connect to the switch via Telnet or the web interface as it has been reset back to factory settings.

I have hit a brick wall as I do not know what to try next. Do I have the wrong serial cable?

Has anyone one else encountered this same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A null-modem cable should work... But in this case, just reset the device to its factory settings.

**To execute the factory default reset on the switch, perform these steps:**

> 1. Simultaneously press the Reset and Clear buttons on the front of the switch with a paperclip.
> 2. Continue to hold the Clear button while releasing the Reset button.
> 3. When the Self Test LED begins to blink, release the Clear button.

The switch will then complete its self test and begin operating with its configuration restored to the factory default settings.

The switch should also obtain a DHCP address if you have a DHCP server on the network.

Comment: Realised my silly mistake and was able to connect to it via DHCP. Thanks!

Comment: What was your mistake?

Comment: FWIW, my V1910-24G doesn't have reset or clear. Ended up using the included console cable and minicom (see comment below)

Answer (score 1):

I found that i needed to turn off hardware flow control in minicom in order to make it work: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProCurve-ProVision-Based/SOLVED-Problem-connecting-to-E2810-48G-console-port-from-Linux/m-p/5667475

Comment: +1 Thank you. Had to install `minicom` for Debian and this tidbit was key to getting through to my procurve 3com v1910-24G.

Comment: A year later, trying to get into the switch. 9600 8n1 hw flow OFF. Minicom see keyspan on /dev/ttyUSB0 ...